# How to get the div behind the div i clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please take a look here at what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/3m6r7ud2/4/

I have the following html page that looks like this:

```
<div class="page_conatiner" id="page1">
    <img src=$file1>
<div class="page_conatiner" id="page2">
    <img src=$file2>
<div class="page_conatiner" id="page3">
    <img src=$file3>
```

And so on.

I also have a fixed button that shows up on hover:

```
    <div class="rotate_button" id="rotate_left" ></div>
    <div class="rotate_button" id="rotate_right" ></div>
```

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).on("click", ".rotate_button", function(){
    var direction = $(this).attr("id");
    var page_num = ?
    rotate_file(page_num,direction)
})
```

The buttons are in fixed locations on the page, and show on hover. When clicking on this button, I want to get which `div` was behind that `div` while clicking
so I could know which of the pages I need to rotate.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. So you should check out how to ask a good question: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you should *at minimum* show us some relevant code BUT even better: put it into a js fiddle to make it easier for us to troubleshoot

Comment: Those divs aren't keyboard accessible. You should use real `<button>` elements (you even use the word "button" yourself).

Comment: Hi, i have added the jquery I'm using, but i think all of my relevent code was in the question.. thx!

Comment: @danielnixon can you please explain why is using a button elment is better then using a regular div, and using jquery for the clicks?

Comment: Try tabbing to those divs and clicking them with a keyboard. See http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html

Comment: What does rotate mean?  Something like this? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I have update the question with jsfiddle to show what im trying to achive

Comment: Why not get the parent of the div you clicked on with $(element).parent() ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not certain what animation you are going for, but there might be a jQuery widget that will do what you want out of the box.  Idk.  The bootstrap one is handy, but maybe all of bootstrap is more than you want: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel.

To answer your question:  I would set a variable somewhere that keeps track of the current page num.  Set it to 0 (or 1 if that's the first page number) when the page loads, and then in your click handler, increment it by 1.  And then make sure to reset it to 0  (or 1) again when it gets high enough to start over. Does that answer your question?